How does Coq guess `i` is decreasing?
As far as I know, fix must be called with a decreasing argument.
In the following code, i is the decreasing argument of rectS_fix,
so rectS_fix should be applied to i'.
However, rectS_fix is applied to i0,
which is merely bound by a λ-abstraction.
Therefore, I am surprised that Coq accepts the following code
and am curious about the mechanism Coq uses to determine whether an argument is decreasing.
Module Fin.
Inductive t : nat -> Set :=
  | FZ (n : nat) : t (S n)
  | FS (n : nat) (i : t n) : t (S n).
#[global] Arguments FZ {n}%nat.
#[global] Arguments FS {n}%nat i.
Lemma case0 {phi : Fin.t O -> Type}
  : forall i, phi i.
Proof.
  intros i.
  exact (
    match i as i in Fin.t n return (match n as m return Fin.t m -> Type with O => phi | S m' => fun _ => unit end) i with
    | @FZ n' => tt
    | @FS n' i' => tt
    end
  ).
Defined.
Lemma rectS (phi : forall n, Fin.t (S n) -> Type)
  (phiFZ : forall n : nat, phi n (@FZ n))
  (phiFS : forall n : nat, forall i : Fin.t (S n), phi n i -> phi (S n) (@FS (S n) i))
  : forall n, forall i, phi n i.
Proof.
  exact (
    fix rectS_fix (n : nat) (i : Fin.t (S n)) {struct i} : phi n i :=
    match i as i in Fin.t n return (match n return Fin.t n -> Type with O => fun _ => unit | S n' => phi n' end) i with
    | @FZ m => phiFZ m
    | @FS m i' => (match m as m return forall i : Fin.t m, phi m (@FS m i) with O => Fin.case0 | S m' => fun i0 => phiFS m' i0 (rectS_fix m' i0) end) i'
    end
  ).
Defined.
End Fin.

Questions

What is the mechanism by which Coq determines that an argument is decreasing?
Why does Coq allow this code?



The mechanism in charge of detecting whether a recursive call is "decreasing" is called the guard condition. Unfortunately, in order to allow for subtle examples like yours, it is quite a complicated piece of machinery, and one which is sadly not very well documented…

In your case what happens is that the guard is able to work modulo what is called a "commutative cut", ie a β-redex blocked by a pattern-matching. Intuitively, it is safe to apply a recursive call to i0, because if the pattern-matching ever reaches that branch, then i0 will be replaced by i', which is a (strict) subterm.



According to a paper written by Gyesik Lee and Benjamin Werner,

Appendix B. Constrained Typing


Note that not all fix-point definitions can be accepted because of the possibility of non-normalizing terms. If one of the arguments belongs to an inductive type, then the function starts with a case analysis, and recursive calls are performed on variables coming from patterns and representing subterms. This is the usual restriction implemented in Coq when a case distinction with respect to a distinguished inductive type in a definition of a (mutual) recursive function occurs. These restrictions are imposed by the so-called guarded-by-destructors condition defined by [Giménez(1995)]. Here, we follow the simplified version
given by [Paulin-Mohring(1996)] by using constrained typing.


The constraints will be imposed with respect to a variable $z$ and an inductive specification $\Delta_I$, $\Delta_C$, and they have three forms: the empty constraint $\epsilon$, the constraint $<_z$, which describes the structural smallness with respect to $z$, and the constraint $=_z$, which describes the equivalence to $z$. The constraints will be added to any occurrence of a variable in a term. Let $\mathbf{c}$, $\mathbf{d}$, ... vary over constraints. The judgments of constrained typing have the form



References.

PROOF-IRRELEVANT MODEL OF CC WITH PREDICATIVE
INDUCTION AND JUDGMENTAL EQUALITY

